# I have to learn Typo3 or Drupal and I don't know where to start

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, typo3, backend

So we got a great project and we absolutely have to learn Typo3 or Drupal for it quickly. I already know some basic things.
I did the installation correctly for both, I know how to set up a basic Site using Fluid Template in Typo3 and I know how to set up a basic template in drupal without any styles.

My Problem now is how do I style a website since typo3 or drupal doesn't have a field for classes (The fields just get some random ids) and also how can I build a website with multiple sections where I have to style each section individually.

If you have any links to good tutorials or anything else that explains what I need to know I would appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by "field for classes"?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler How can I add custom classes to elements? Or do I split the content in the backend box for box?

Comment: This seems like a very broad question. Check out the docs on both first, they are well documented systems after all.

Comment: @RDAxRoadkill oh sorry I didn't know this is broad. I really tried to narrow it down.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by "field for classes". Do you mean the "class" attribute in HTML? Please be as specific as possible in your question.

Comment: For TYPO3, you might find this useful: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i think you understand HTML/CSS and know that TYPO3,... are content management systems. They're wrapping your content (saved to the database) with a template like HTML Files to send the result to the browser as a full rendered website.

ThomasLöffler already gave you the hint to read the documentation on both websites to make your choice which one you want to use. I prefer TYPO3, but the start many years ago wasn't easy. So i could you explain a little bit, and on a very short way what you need to do... After all please read the docs on typo3.org (Gettin started guide or something)

In TYPO3 you need to include and build your HTML Template. Prefered with the FLUID Template Engine / Framework. After that you need to set it with the TYPO3 TypoScript as your main template.

The content templates like  will be rendered by the TYPO3 Extension "fluid_styled_content". This extension has also fluid templates to render the content object into a html output. Before you have enough knowledge about typo3 it's not recomended to change them.

The main thing is, that you need to include a stylesheet (css) file in your site. In TYPO3's TypoScript it's for example like this:

```
page.includeCSS.file100 = path/to/your/css/mystyle.css
```

Thats the very short overview and very little explanation what to do. But as Thomas said, you need to understand both and decide for one of them. And of course you need to read the docs first a little bit, before you ask. That would help you and each of us, to give you better answers. Good luck!

TYPO3 Gett started:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/GettingStartedTutorial/Introduction/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can learn a lot of things if you take a look into the code of the official introduction package (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/introduction/) The package can simply installed over the extension manager -> get preconfigured distributions

Or you just use it as a basis to build your own layout. You do not have to reinvent the wheel ;)